# How to make Angular JS show properly array with elements with "&nbsp"

Tags: angularjs

I am using the latest version of Angular JS - 1.2, and I have an array with objects that have properties with `&nbsp;` like this: `first&nbsp;second&nbsp;last` instead of single spaces. How can I make Angular replace them with " "? I have tried to use `ng-bind-html`, but it does not seem to work.

My Controller:

```
app.controller('ChatController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.messages = [];

    var setMessages = function (data) {         
        $scope.messages = data || [];
    };

    $http.get(url).success(setMessages)
}
```

My view using Jade:

```
ul#chat
    li(ng-repeat="message in messages")
        span.name(ng-bind-html="message.by")
        span.message {{message.text}}
```

When I try to use ng-bind-html I get this error:

```
Error: [$sce:unsafe]
    at Error (native)
at http://localhost/libraries/angular/angular.min.js:6:450
at $get.e (http://localhost/libraries/angular/angular.min.js:117:34)
at $get.getTrusted (http://localhost/libraries/angular/angular.min.js:118:327)
at Object.$get.e.(anonymous function) [as getTrustedHtml (http://localhost/libraries/angular/angular.min.js:120:71)
at Object.fn (http://localhost/libraries/angular/angular.min.js:192:234)
at k.$get.k.$digest (http://localhost/libraries/angular/angular.min.js:109:213)
at k.$get.k.$apply (http://localhost/libraries/angular/angular.min.js:112:173)
at h (http://localhost/libraries/angular/angular.min.js:72:300)
at w (http://localhost/libraries/angular/angular.min.js:77:288)
```

Comment: did you try readiing the `$sce` docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html is considered 'unsafe' by angular so will be escaped (i.e. `$nbsp;` will get rendered literally not as whitespace)

Add module dependency to `ngSanitize` and add to your controller a dependency on `$sce`

.controller('ChatController', [['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.messages = [];

```
var setMessages = function (data) {
    angular.forEach(data, funciton(msg) {
        $sce.trustAsHtml(msg.text);
    });
    $scope.messages = data || [];
};

$http.get(url).success(setMessages);
```

}])

the `$sce.trustAsHtml(msg.text)` call marks the text as "trusted" so angular will render it as HTML

Answer (score 0):

I was able to chage them with a filter

```
app.filter('removeNonBreakingSpaces', function () {
    return  function (text) {
        return text.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
    }
});


ul#chat
    li(ng-repeat="message in messages")
        span.message {{message.text | removeNonBreakingSpaces}}
```